# how to find corresponding source code or definitions from site: android.git.kernel.org

Tags: android

Some pre-define variant, for example:attribute value, layout 
view .etc. (e.g.android:galleryItemBackground), where i can find the 
source code(exactly implementation or definition) in site: 
android.git.kernel.org,

Comment: thanks in advance! if anyone knows pls tell me!

Answer (score 0):

You can either download the whole project [here](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) and browse it to find the sources.
Or on [android git kernel](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core;hb=HEAD) and look into the repositories...

Hope this helps and that I have understood you correctly